# TextBox.Background property in VisualBrush behaving weirdly

Tags: wpf, xaml

Coming off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714249/textblock-background-property-removing-stretch) question, I have a textbox defined as this:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Background>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Background="Blue" Opacity="0.5" Text="155"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </TextBox.Background>
</TextBox>
```

This results in a `TextBox` like this:

[image: TextBox with Background]

Now if I remove the background property, the `TextBox`looks like this:

[image: TextBox without background]

What I want is to achieve the second image with a colored background. In the first image for example, I want the background colour to fill the remaining whitespaces as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding `Grid` with background also as `VisualBrush` and in that grid you can add your `TextBox`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill">
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <Rectangle Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Blue" Opacity="0.5" />
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Style>               
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />                    
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Gray" Opacity="0.5" Text="155"/>
                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                        </VisualBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Doing this is going to make everything, including anything typed into the TextBox, semi-transparent.

Comment: @JohnBowen check my answer again. I solved that problem by using `VisualBrush` in grid.

Comment: Rather than adding all that complexity you could just do Background="#800000FF" on the Grid.

Comment: Yes it's complexity but if we will change color in the future we can write `Stroke="Red"` in `Rectangle`. We don't have write hexadecimal color value.

Comment: This is good. However, I need the background to somehow be part of the VisualBrush/StackPanel/TextBlock but nothing outside it since this TextBox is supposed to be a custom control and I need to be able to change the background colour based on certain conditions.

Comment: If you don't want to write hex colors it's still much easier and more performant to write the expansion of the brush: <Grid.Background><SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" Opacity="0.5"/></Grid.Background>

Comment: @DukeCyrillus you can do this with my solution. What conditions do you have?

Comment: @kmatyaszek The TextBox is actually a custom control inheriting TextBox. Its background is  a TextBlock that displays the character count and currently the count changes colour when a certain number of characters remain. However, I want the background to change color as well and the logic to change the color should reside in the code for the custom control, which is why I wanted it to be the TextBlock Background